# Know whether user selected a sub menu item or not MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

[image]

I have an MFC application which has a sub menu under the rectangle item in the menu. The sub menu black is not getting selected as the user clicks from the GUI. I want the interface such as the user selects the sub menu, a tick mark should appear besides it. But was unable to do so. This is the code I tried for getting user focus as he clicks it.

```
This is for ON_COMMAND:  

ON_COMMAND(ID_IMAGEOPTIONS_IMAGEWITHBLACKRECTANGLES, &CMainFrame::OnToggleTestBlackRectangles)      

void CMainFrame::OnToggleTestBlackRectangles()
{
 CMenu menu;
 menu.LoadMenu(IDR_MAINFRAME);
 menu.CheckMenuItem(ID_IMAGEOPTIONS_IMAGEWITHBLACKRECTANGLES, MF_CHECKED);
 UINT SST = menu.GetMenuState(ID_RECTANGLE_BLACK, MF_BYCOMMAND);
 }

This is for ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI:

ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_IMAGEOPTIONS_IMAGEWITHBLACKRECTANGLES, &CMainFrame::OnCheckMenu)
void CMainFrame::OnCheckMenu(CCmdUI *pCmdUI)
{

   pCmdUI->SetCheck(0);

}
```

Even the user clicks the sub menu, the tick mark doesn't appear and even the getmenustate returns a 0 instead of a non - zero value.

Any help appreciated!!!

Comment: That code doesn't do anything. Do you want to add a check mark next to command?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I just updated my post and wrote the complete functions I have implemented.

Comment: Declare a member variable `BOOL m_black;` initialize it to true or false. Change `OnToggle()` to `{m_black = !m_black;}` change `OnCheckMenu` to `{pCmdUI->SetCheck(m_black);}`

Answer (score 2):

The UI doesn't update by itself, you have to do it.

Please read: [How to: Update User-Interface Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72t5ykb7.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: You should elaborate on your answer.  If your link becomes invalid, the value of your answer suffers.